A variation of Riesz Lemma
Given a normed space $X$, a closed proper subspace $Y$ and $\alpha\in (0,1)$, the Riesz Lemma states that there is $x\in X$ such that $||x||=1$ and $d(x,Y)>\alpha$. Observe that also $d(-x,Y)=d(x,Y)>\alpha$. That is, the distance from the unit sphere of $\langle x \rangle$ (where $\langle A\rangle$ denotes the linear span of $A$) to $Y$ is at least $\alpha$.
I'm looking for a proof or counterexample for the following variation of the Riesz Lemma:
Given a normed space $X$, a closed proper subspace $Y$ and $\alpha\in (0,1)$, there is $x\in X$ such that the distance from $\langle x\rangle$ to the unit sphere of $Y$ is at least $\alpha$.
I am mostly interested in positive answers, so partial positive answers would be nice if the result is false. Particularly, I'm only concerned with Banach spaces, so this can be assumed without problem.

@daw I'm asking about the distance of $\langle x\rangle$ to the unit sphere of $Y$. Even if $d(x,Y)$ is larger than $\alpha$, it's (a priori) possible that $||\lambda x-y||<\alpha$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb K$ and $y\in Y$, $||y||=1$

Any constant less than $2(/(\sqrt{5}+1)$ is possible.

@RyszardSzwarc how do you get that value? And that is the highest value that is possible to ensure the existence?

Sorry, I have made a mistake. I can do $1/2,$ but that is nearly obvious.
